# Saber se o numero é ímpar ou par

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber por que não acontece nada com meu código. Até a variável `n` aparece o alerta, mas depois não acontece mais nada.

```js
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total=n/2;
if(n/2=0){
    alert("Par");
}
if(n/2=1){
    alert("Impar");
}
alert(total);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Em `if`s comparações não usam um sinal `=`, mas sim dois sinais ou três, como no exemplo:

- `if (n/2 == 0) {` comparação de igual
- `if (n/2 === 0) {` comparação de idêntico

O seu código deve ser algo como:

> **Nota:** seu código não verifica se o valor é ímpar ou par realmente, para isto use um destes métodos descritos em *Verificando se é impar ou par* e este exemplo é apenas para entender como usar as `if`s:

```
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total=n/2;
if(n/2 == 0){
    alert("Par");
}
if(n/2 == 1){
    alert("Impar");
}
alert(total);
```

O uso de `if` desta maneira `if (1=1)`  no JavaScript irá emitir o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

## Verificando se é ímpar ou par

- Aritmético remainder (módulo): `if (variavel % 2 === 0)` se igual a `0` é par, se não é ímpar
- Aritmético remainder (módulo): `if (variavel % 2 !== 0)` se diferente de `0` é ímpar, se não é par
- Com bitwise AND: `if (variavel & 1)` se for `0` é par, se não é ímpar
- Com bitwise AND e NOT: `if (~ variavel & 1)` se for `0` é ímpar, se não é par

Conforme o teste de performance não houve diferenças significativas entre o operador bitwise e o aritmético: https://jsbench.me/c8ktn71mzb/1

Exemplo:

```js
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total = n/2;

if(n & 1){
    alert("Impar");
} else {
    alert("Par");
}

alert(total);
```

## Operadores de comparação

### Equality operators

- Igual/Equivalente (`==`) é usado para comparar se os valores são iguais, por exemplo:

```js
console.log(1 == 1);     // true
console.log("1" == 1);   // true
console.log(1 == '1');   // true
console.log(0 == false); // true
```

- Diferente/não equivalente (`!=`) é usado para fazer comparações não são iguais:

```js
console.log(1 != 2);     // true
console.log(1 != "1");   // false
console.log(1 != '1');   // false
console.log(1 != true);  // false
console.log(0 != false); // false
```

- Idêntico / estritamente equivalente (`===`) é usado para comparar se ambos valores são do mesmo tipo de valor, diferenciando números inteiros de com ponto flutuante, booleano de inteiro, inteiro de string, etc:

```js
console.log(3 === 3);     // true
console.log(3 === '3');   // false
console.log(0 === false); //false
```

- Não idêntico/estritamente *não* equivalente (`!==`) é usado para comparar se ambos valores são de tipos de valores diferentes:

```js
console.log(3 !== 3);     // false
console.log(3 !== '3');   // true
console.log(0 !== false); // true
console.log(0 !== 0);     // false
```

Answer (score 17):

1. para fazer comparações se usa `==`.
   Exemplo: 
   `if(x == y)`
2. para saber se o número é par ou ímpar é melhor usar o operador resto(%).

O código no final poderia ficar assim:

```js
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total=n/2;
if(n%2 == 0){
 alert("Par");
}else{
 alert("Impar");
}
alert(total);
```

Se o n resto 2 for igual a 0 é par, senão é ímpar.

Comment: Lembrado que o operador `==` compara se o valor de dois objetos é igual e o operador `===` compara se o valor e os tipos dos objetos são iguais. Por exemplo `'true' == true`  resulta em `true`; `'true' === true` retorna `false`.

Answer (score 13):

Para saber se um dado numero é par ou ímpar a melhor maneira é usando o [operador modulus/resto, `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). Que retorna o resto da divisão de dois numeros.

Se `n % 2` der resto zero, o numero é par, e impar caso contrário.

```js
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total = n / 2;
var resultado = total % 2 == 0 ? 'Par' : 'Impar';
alert(total + ' é ' + resultado);
```

Answer (score 5):

Outra forma interessante (e econômica) de fazer essa verificação é por meio da operação bit-a-bit `&`

**Exemplos**

- Ímpar

  `alert(3 & 1 ? "Ímpar" : "Par"); //imprime "Ímpar", pois retorna o ultimo bit da operação bit-a-bit & (Nesse caso, 1)`

  ```
      11
      01 &
      01
  ```
- Par

  `alert(4 & 1 ? "Ímpar" : "Par"); //imprime "Par", pois retorna o ultimo bit da operação bit-a-bit & (Nesse caso, 0)`

  ```
       100
       001 &
       000
  ```

Answer (score 4):

```
var n = prompt("Digite um numero");
var total = n/2;
if(n / 2 = 0) {
    alert("Par");
}
if(n / 2 = 1){
    alert("Impar");
}
alert(total);
```

Amigo quando vc usa:
`var 'total = n/2'` você está apenas dividindo este valor, não tem como saber se é par ou ímpar deste jeito.

Você precisa utilizar o operador `%` que vai dar o resultado da sobra da divisão, e por meio desta sobra é que se sabe se é par ou ímpar. Bem simples neh ?

apenas troque:

```
var total = n / 2;
```

por:

```
var tola = n % 2;
```

outra coisa não é:

```
if(n/2 = 1){
}
```

mas sim :

```
if(total == 0){
    alert("par");
}
```

resumindo, o código pode ficar assim:

```
var n = prompt("digite numero");
var resto = n % 2;

if (resto == 0) {
    console.log(n + " par");
} else {
    console.log(n + " impar");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

creio que tem uns erros, veja:

```
var n = prmpt('digite o numero');
var total=n/2;
if(n/2==0){
alert('par");
}
```

obs: perceba que o operador de igualdade são dois == e nao um so = . 
na outra declaração if tambem é preciso ajustar ok.

```js
var n = prompt("digite um numero");
var total=n/2;
if(n/2=0){
    alert("par");
}
if(n/2=1){
    alert("impar");
}
alert(total);
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>exercicio02</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
       
        //Complementando o raciocínio citado a cima. Usa um Template strings ${}
        

        var n = prompt('Digite um número ');
        var resultado = n % 2 ===0? 'par':'impar'; //função ternária é bem básica
            alert(`número ${n} é ${resultado}`); // a propriedade do alert está entre crase.

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

//Complementando o raciocínio citado a cima. Usa um Template strings ${}
//função ternária é bem básica:

var n = prompt('Digite um número ');
        var resultado = n % 2 ===0? 'par':'impar';
            alert(`número ${n} é ${resultado}`); // a propriedade dos alert está entre crase.