# Ir para determinado link dependendo da página

Tags: javascript, html, html5, if, condição

Estou desenvolvendo um quiz com vários temas, mas na hora de colocar para ele ir para determinada página dependendo de qual página a pessoa está. Pensei em usar o `if` mas ele sempre vai para o ultimo `if`, vou colocar o código aqui. Alguém sabe onde errei?

```
var url = window.location.href;

if(url = 'tela03.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela04.html'
}else if(url = 'tela05.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela06.html'
} else if(url = 'tela07.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela08.html'
}
else (url = 'tela09.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela10.html'
}
```

Comment: Errou em vários pontos. Vamos lá, quando dá um `if` você deve comprar com 2 ou 3 iguais `==` ou `===`. O comando else não pode ter verificação entre parênteses.

Comment: Seria ideal você depurar. Você pode usar o navegador pausando linha por linha para acompanhar o que está acontecendo. E também pode escrever alguns console.log() das variáveis e em trechos após os comportamentos para ver o que está sendo alterado. Vai ajudar muito trabalhar desta forma, principalmente utilizando o depurador.

Comment: Relacionado: [Saber se o numero é ímpar ou par](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64059/3774)

Comment: Não acredito que sua abordagem seja boa para fazer estes redirecionamentos, mas se for usar a URL atual para isso, use [`Location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) ao invés de `Location.href`...

Comment: Não conserte os erros que tinha na pergunta, isto invalida a respostas dadas, se o erro está aí as pessoas responderam baseando-se neles, mudando a pergunta ela até deixa de ser válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí, não sei se resolve tudo.

Tinha operador de atribuição `=` usado no lugar de comparação `==`. Não tem necessidade de `===` porque você tem certeza dos tipos que estão sendo comparados.

faltava `if` depois do `else` para funcionar. Tem respostas que muda a semântica de execução do algoritmo fazendo algo ser executado por *default*, que é diferente do código original que só deve executar se tiver uma condição específica.

Falta ponto e vírgula, estava bem desorganizado.

Além disso você não pode comparar só com a página, tem que dar o endereço completo, a *string* que vem de `window.location.href` tem um URL completo, com protocolo, domínio, porta (pode ser a *default*), o arquivo da página e eventualmente complementos, tem que comparar com o que vem. Poderia ser por exemplo `http://www.thi100.com/tela03.html`.

Eu coloquei um `console.log()` ali para mostrar o que vem, aqui no SOpt não vai funcionar bem por causa do *script* de execução, mas executando na sua página vai mostrar qual é o URL que está vindo. Aí você pega a informação que vem em cada cenário e pode adaptar na condição para ser o que deseja (teste em cada página que puder receber para ver cada situação, não tente adivinhar o que vem, programação não é jogo de adivinhação, é algo exato que se trabalha com dados reais coletados de forma mecânica e precisa).

```js
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);
if (url == 'tela03.html') {
    window.location.href = 'tela04.html';
} else if (url == 'tela05.html') {
    window.location.href = 'tela06.html';
} else if (url == 'tela07.html') {
    window.location.href = 'tela08.html';
} else if (url == 'tela09.html') {
    window.location.href = 'tela10.html';
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Ifs.js).

Eu acho que isso está conceitualmente errado, mas não vou entrar nesse mérito.

Answer (score 1):

A correção do seu código deveria ficar +/- assim:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if(url === 'tela03.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela04.html'
}else if(url === 'tela05.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela06.html'
} else if(url === 'tela07.html'){
  window.location.href = 'tela08.html'
}
else {
  window.location.href = 'tela10.html'
}
```

ou melhor poderia utilizar switch:

```
var url = window.location.href;
switch (url) {
    case 'tela03.html':
        window.location.href = 'tela04.html';
        break;
    case 'tela05.html':
        window.location.href = 'tela06.html';
        break;
    case 'tela07.html':
        window.location.href = 'tela08.html';
        break;
    defult:
        window.location.href = 'tela10.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as suas condições de `if` estão incorretas... Você apenas alterou o valor da variável `url` dentro das condições `if`, e a variável não retornou nenhum valor `booleano`, por isso todas as condições `if` foram ignoradas...

E outra: o código `window.location.href` retorna a url que você está... E não o arquivo do diretório atual...

Se a sua url for **http://localhost/projeto/tela03.html**, então `var url = window.location.href;` irá retornar o valor **http://localhost/projeto/tela03.html** e não tela03.html.

Logo o seu código `if` deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

```
if(url == 'url que você está')
```

Answer (score 0):

O `location.href` retorna a URL toda e não apenas a página atual. Em vez de redirecionar para uma página baseando-se na URL ou no nome da página, ao meu ver seria mais prático inserir em cada página uma variável que a identifique.

Por exemplo, na página `tela03.html` coloque uma variável no script:

```
<script>var tela = 3;</script>
```

Na página `tela04.html` coloque:

```
<script>var tela = 4;</script>
```

E assim em cada página.

E crie um `.js` externo e chame-o no final do `body` de cada página:

```
<script src="redirecionamento.js"></script>
```

No arquivo `redirecionamento.js` você faz os `if`'s, verificando a variável `tela` para saber em qual página está e pra onde vai:

```
if(tela == 3){
   location = "tela04.html";
}else if(tela == 4){
   location = "tela05.html";
}
etc...
```

Pode também fazer algo mais dinâmico, sem usar `if`'s, apenas incrementando a variável `tela` com +1 e redirecionar para a próxima página:

```
location = "tela"+ ("0" + (tela + 1)).slice(-2) +".html";
```

Se tiver na página `tela03.html`, irá para a página `tela04.html` e assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score -1):

Na condição do seu if/else você está sempre atribuindo um valor ao invés de fazer uma comparação.

Por exemplo, onde está:

```
if ( url = 'pagina.html' )
```

deveria ser:

```
if ( url == 'página.html' )
```

Além disso, `window.location.href` retornará a url atual dessa forma:

```
https://site.com.br/pagina.html
```

Para fazer o que você quer, poderia usar `window.location.pathname`, que retornaria dessa forma:

```
/pagina.html
```

Aplicando essas mudanças:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

if( url == '/tela03.html' ){
  window.location.href = 'tela04.html'
}else if( url == '/tela05.html' ){
  window.location.href = 'tela06.html'
} else if( url == '/tela07.html' ){
  window.location.href = 'tela08.html'
}
else( url == '/tela09.html '){
  window.location.href = 'tela10.html'
}
```